# Pointer pointing older address while printing the array elements through loop

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-address

I want to read array elements defined in main function through another user defined function. The array is 2D and it shows the first three elements correctly but as next loop starts the address pointed by that pointer is 2 step back from the intended address. Why's that?
Here is the main function calling the frame() function where the problem is:

```
void main(){
    char dec,player[2][20];
    int i,counter=0,palo,winner=0;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        printf("Enter Player%d's name: ",(i+1));
        scanf("%s",player[i]);                  //ASK PLAYER NAME
    }
    startAgain:                             //GAME RESTART POINT
    system("cls");
    palo=0;
    char spot[][3]={"123","456","789"};

    //------------------MAIN GAME AREA-------------------------------
    for(counter=0;counter<9;counter++,palo++){
        frame(*spot);
        read(&palo,*spot,*player);
        palo %=2;
    }
}
```

Here is the frame() function:

```
void frame(char *count){
    int i,j;
    printf("\t\t\t");
    line(24);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("\t\t\t");
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("|   %c   ",(*(count+i)+j));
        }
        printf("|\n\t\t\t");
        line(24);
    }
}
```

The intended output is :

```
1        2       3
4        5       6
7        8       9
```

What it displays:

```
1        2       3
2        3       4
3        4       5
```

Comment: `printf("|   %c   ",(*(count+i)+j));` change to `printf("|   %c   ",(*(count+i * 3)+j));` (although I would do bigger changes like passing `spot` as `char**` etc)

Comment: @Anish Chapagai The code is awful. Bad code is always a reason of bugs.

Comment: Thanks it solved. But why " *3 " ?

Comment: Change `char spot[][3]={"123","456","789"};` to `char spot[][4]={"123","456","789"};` ... you need space for the `nul`-terminator in each of the string literals.

Comment: It would be much easier if you passed `spot` to the function and used normal array indexing, instead of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  What's wrong with this code? Am I developing some bad habits?

Comment: @AdrianMole He never uses string functions on them, so the null terminators are not really needed.

Comment: @Barmar but the arrays will be initialised incorrectly, as the data still includes the `nul`s

Comment: @AdrianMole No, it doesn't do that if there isn't room.

Comment: @AnishChapagai Since thats the size of the 2nd dimension. You essentially rendered your 2D spot array to 1D in your function so now like a[i][j] not valid, but a[i * <2nd dimm size> + j]

Comment: @AnishChapagai For example the function main shall be declared like int main( void ). Variables should be declared where they are used. Otherwise their meanings are unclera.

Comment: @Barmar OK - I was getting confused between C and that other language that some folks think is like C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make life easier for yourself and others, use normal array indexing instead of pointer arithmetic.

```
    for(counter=0;counter<9;counter++,palo++){
        frame(spot);
        read(&palo,spot,player);
        palo %=2;
    }

...
void frame(char count[][3]){
    int i,j;
    printf("\t\t\t");
    line(24);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("\t\t\t");
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("|   %c   ",count[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n\t\t\t");
        line(24);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that array is just a pointer pointing to the first base address but is it myth or a fact that using pointer with array reduces memory usage? Isn't using pointer with array is just like using double pointer?  I wanted to learn to code efficiently from the beginning so I did that.

Comment: This makes no difference in efficiency, and makes the code much more readable and understandable. Worry about that first when learning.